# Trace Rspec's get request routing in controller action spec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, controller, request

I am trying to test a simple controller action in a moduled controller. However, my `get :index` request returns a 404, instead of a 200 response. Is there a way to trace the routing of this `get` request?

```
require "spec_helper"

describe Admin::WidgetsController do
  describe "GET index" do
    it "has a 200 status code" do
      get :index
      response.code.should eq("200")
    end
  end
end
```

The controller looks like as you would expect:

```
class Admin::WidgetsController < Admin::ApplicationController
  respond_to :html, :xml, :json
  def index
    respond_with(@content = "content")
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like something is wrong with your routing. On the console you can run this to see what routes are available to your app:

```
       $> rake routes
```

I'm pretty sure the following, when it fails, will show you what it's being redirected to

```
describe Admin::WidgetsController do
  describe "GET index" do
    it "has a 200 status code" do
      get :index
      response.should redirect_to(:action => 'other_action')
    end
  end
end
```

You can check out these links for more info:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

http://old.rspec.info/rails/writing/controllers.html

Comment: Sorry, you are not actually redirecting. Instead try something like this: 'params_from(:get, "/hello/world").should == {:controller => "hello", :action => "world"}'

Comment: The above sets an expectation on the route and the failure should give you more info.